# Display data from an API when clicking a button. Using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the data of each character when I click the Info Button.
I know it is because in the `onButtonClickHandler` function it can not see the state. I have also tried `this.state.person` but it gives me an error saying "can not read state". And if I try just `state.person` it will give me "undefined".

What is the best way to do that? Thank you

API Link: https://swapi.dev/people/

```
import React from "react";

export default class FetchActors extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ person: data.results, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.person.length) {
      return <div>didn't get a person</div>;
    }

   function onButtonClickHandler(state) {
      console.log(state.person);
    };


    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Actors</h1>
        {this.state.person.map(person =>(
        <div>
          <div>
            {person.name}
            <button onClick={onButtonClickHandler}>Info</button>

          </div>

        </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={onButtonClickHandler}>Enter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your function `onButtonClickHandler` as a function that takes one argument, and logs the `person` property of that argument.  **The argument `state` in your function has nothing to do with the `state` of your component.**  As javascript sees it, they are two totally unrelated variables which just happen to have the same name.

```
function onButtonClickHandler(state) {
   console.log(state.person);
};
```

When `button` calls `onClick`, it passes the event as the argument.  So your `onButtonClickHandler` is logging the `person` property of the event, which obviously doesn't exist.

Since you are not using any information from the event, your function should take no arguments.  As others have said, you should also move this function outside of the `render()` method so that it is not recreated on each render.  The suggestion to use `bind` is not necessary if you use an arrow function, since these bind automatically.

```
export default class FetchActors extends React.Component {
  /*...*/

  onButtonClickHandler = () => {
     console.log(this.state.person);
  };

}
```

Inside `render()`

```
<button onClick={this.onButtonClickHandler}>Enter</button>
```

You could also define the function inline, as an arrow function which takes no arguments:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.person)}>Enter</button>
```

If you are new to react, I recommend learning with function components rather than class components.

**Edit:**

Updating this answer regarding our comments.  I was so caught up in explaining the errors from doing the wrong thing that I neglected to explain how to do the right thing!

> I am trying to display the data of each character when I click the Info Button.

Once we call the API, we already have the info loaded for each character.  We just need to know which one we want to display.  You can add a property `expanded` to your `state` and use it to store the index (or `id` or `name`, whatever you want really) of the currently expanded item.

When we loop through to show the name and info button, we check if that character is the expanded one.  If so, we show the character info.

Now the `onClick` handler of our button is responsible for setting `state.expanded` to the character that we clicked it from.

```
{this.state.person.map((person, i) =>(
<div>
  <div>
    {person.name}
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({expanded: i})}>Info</button>
    {this.state.expanded === i && (
      <CharacterInfo
        key={person.name}
        person={person}
      />
    )}
  </div>
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dust-6sb17?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I tried something similar to this but it gives me "Failed to compile" on the 

onButtonClickHandler = () => {
     console.log(this.state.person);
  };

Comment: It should be fine.  Are you putting that function at the top-level of your component?

Comment: I think what you are actually trying to do is something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dust-6sb17?file=/src/App.js), but with the info formatted, obviously.

Comment: YESSSSSS, exactly. Should I use a <ul> tag to display the info formatted?

Comment: You could do that.  Or maybe a [table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/). If you're showing more than 1 or 2 stats I would actually make a function component `CharacterInfo` that takes the character properties as props and handles rendering the info.  Then from your main component you just call `<CharacterInfo {...person} />` using the spread operator `...` to pass down the values of `person` as individual props.

Comment: Or pass it down as one prop.  It doesn't really matter which as long as what you pass is what the component expects to recieve.

Comment: Thank you Linda, I will do that. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Please correct me if I'm wrong*

The most likely reason why you are seeing this is because of the way javascript internally works. The syntax:

```js
function xyz() {

}
```

has an implicit `this`

Maybe try changing your code from:

```js
function onButtonClickHandler(state) {
  console.log(state.person);
};
```

to:

```js
const onButtonClickHandler = () => {
  console.log(this.state.person);
};
```

Further Reading: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:%7E:text=Does%20not%20have%20its%20own%20bindings)

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways you can resolve your issue; I'll give you the more common approach.

1. You want to define your click handler as a class (instance) method, rather than declare it as a function inside the render method (you *can* define it as a function inside the render method, but that's probably not the best way to do it for a variety of reasons that are out of scope).
2. You will also have to bind it's 'this' value to the class (instance) because click handlers are triggered asynchronously.
3. Finally, add a button and trigger the fetch on click:

```
class Actors extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    actors: undefined,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchActors = this.fetchActors.bind(this);
  }

  async fetchActors() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ actors: data.results, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Actors: ', this.state.actors);
    return <button onClick={this.fetchActors}>fetch actors</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This give me an error on bind. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" in this line of code ` this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

Comment: sorry about that, i had the method name wrong. it should be `fetchActors` not `handleClick` - see the updated code

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes i takes react a min to load the updated state.

```
import React from "react";

export default class FetchActors extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    if(!data.results) { // throw error }
    this.setState({ person: data.results, loading: false }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.person) // log out your data to verify
});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading || !this.state.person) { // wait for person data
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }else{


   function onButtonClickHandler(state) { // just make a componentDidUpdate function
      console.log(state.person);
    };


    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Actors</h1>
        {this.state.person.map(person =>(
        <div>
          <div>
            {person.name}
            <button onClick={onButtonClickHandler}>Info</button>

          </div>

        </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={onButtonClickHandler}>Enter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}}
```